# control display or enable action of buttons depending on scroll till end of webview

Tags: android, button, webview, scroll, scrollview

I have a requirement to display two buttons, one at the top and one at the bottom of a webview in an android activity's layout.

The display and action of these buttons is to be controlled depending on the user's scroll position.

When the a special module/part of the app is launched, the top button is visible but disabled, the user must scroll till bottom of webview, only then the bottom button appears on the screen. to clarify, buttons are native and not inside webview or above it.

I prepared mocks to explain:

**start screen**
[image]

**user scrolls**
(apparently reads the agreement, which is a webview)

**end screen**
[image]

how can i control the display of the buttons in this fashion?

so far i have been able to display two buttons above and below webview, but i dont know how to hide the lower one until user scrolls to the bottom of the webview. (or enable when reached the bottom, assuming default state is disabled)

My layout.xml is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/starttop"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/start_message_top" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/explanationwebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closebutton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/close" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startbottom"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/start_message_bottom" />
```

I believe ScrollView can help me out, please guide.

Comment: You can put button inside your html as well. and add a JavaSciptInterface to obtain the click event to Activity/Fragment(java file).

Comment: @RahulKhurana I don't want to make it more complex. Depending on Javascript is the last thing i would do for this task. the HTML is fetched by an API, if it does not contain the agree button, then my application's flow will be affected, i cannot impose this constraint.

Comment: then you can implement onScrollChanged method of webview to check

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the layout by using this kind of layout.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/starttop"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/start_photo_survey" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closebutton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:gravity="right|end|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="0.9">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/explanationwebview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            </WebView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startbottom"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_photo_survey" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, i need to write onScrollListener to control disable/enable the button's onclick action.